# How to center the subviews of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm a beginner in creating a custom view. I'm trying to create a custom UIView with a scrollview and buttons that will look like this:[image]

I'm adding a view(view with label of page number) inside of scrollView depending on the the number of pages. Is that how it should be?

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

My question is how can I center the subviews of scrollview? and next is what's wrong with this code? Why is that I can only see 1 label inside the view? and the other doesn't show up.  How can I scroll to the selected page if the page number is not visible already in the scrollview?

Here's my code:

```
func addPageNumberViewWithCount(count: Int) {

        var pageNumberViewX: CGFloat! = 0
        let pageNumberViewDistance: CGFloat! = 10

        for i in 1...count {

            let pageNumberView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(pageNumberViewX, 0, 30, 30))
            pageNumberView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            pageNumberView.layer.cornerRadius = pageNumberView.frame.height / 2
            pageNumberView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            pageNumberView.clipsToBounds = true

            // add number label
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(pageNumberViewX, 0, 30, 30))
            label.center = pageNumberView.center
            label.text = "\(i)"
            label.textAlignment = .Center
            pageNumberView.addSubview(label)

            // update x for next view
            pageNumberViewX = pageNumberView.frame.origin.x + pageNumberView.frame.width + pageNumberViewDistance

            // add view inside scrollview
            scrollView.addSubview(pageNumberView)


            if i == count {
                scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageNumberViewX + pageNumberView.frame.width, 30)
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Part of my answer will go to providing a solution to your question,and another part of my answer will go toward strongly suggesting that this not be the method you use to complete your desired tasks.

At this point, AutoLayout and Interface Builder have come a long way. Where they used to be difficult to use because of their inconsistency and unpredictability, they are now highly predictable and consistent as long as you understand the tools and how to use them.

Apple's suggested method for completing this task (which I mostly stand behind) is creating a .xib file (nib) to lay out the base components of the design, and to load the nib into the view or view controller whenever that design should be used. My question for you: have you tried this, or have you determined for some reason that this would be an unsatisfactory solution to your problem? AutoLayout exists to solve these problems not just in allowing you to achieve your desired solution in this one situation but to achieve it in other situations as well, with varying screen sizes and device types.

Now, if you were to simply ignore all of that and continue on your path, there would be a few good ways to handle your problem. One suggested solution I have:

1) Wrap your pageNumberView in another view. Constrain that view to the size of the scrollView. Doing this gives the scrollView content with which to base its scrollable content size, and gives the inner pageNumberView something to compare itself to.
2) Center the pageNumberView horizontally in its container (the new view that we just created).

Doing this, the page numbers should now center themselves in the container until they reach a size where they exceed the width of the scrollView. At that point, they will then continue to expand, making the area horizontally scrollable.

I can provide code examples of how you would do this, but frankly I would much prefer if you scrapped the idea of doing things this way and instead opted for the AutoLayout method at least, and perhaps even the Interface Builder method. I started out with iOS the same way you did, trying to do everything in code. It really isn't the best way to do things, at least with regard to iOS.

Edit: I've provided an example of how this would look in Interface Builder using UINib. I've populated the view with an example of 5 pages to show what it is like. I will see if I can make a GIF or something similar to show what each of the subviews look like.

For the OP, my suggestion would be this: Use this for reference, and go learn the constraints system. It is *extremely unlikely* that you will find success with iOS if you do not learn and utilize the constraints system. Coding in X values to a UIView's frame is only going to create a product with poor, inconsistent performance across devices, and will take much, *much* longer than it would to take the time to learn constraints.

[image: PageNumberView_1]

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your lengthy response, I've read it all. It would be really a great help if you have a better way of accomplishing the view that I'm trying to create.

Comment: @Rhenz Let me see if I can pull out my Mac and Xcode to try to give a decent example of what I'm talking about

Comment: Sure Michael, will wait for response. It would be really great help if you can share a way to achieve my desired view and I will scrap my first idea already.

Comment: I'm working on it now.. It does take some time, so patience will be necessary. @Rhenz

Comment: Oh sorry bout that, I just thought you have some examples already. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Rhenz I've added an example of what it would look like to create a Nib in Interface Builder using AutoLayout and constraints. My suggestion to you is to learn the constraints system and use that as a basis for creating your UI in iOs from here on out. I have created multiple production iOS apps in my life and can guarantee that I would not have found success with any of those if I was attempting to avoid these tools. They are there for a reason and really are the best option for creating UI for iOS apps.

Comment: Hi Michael, the problem is it is not constant to 5 pages only. It could be more. What would you suggest to do if that is the case?

Comment: I understand the dynamic aspect. You can actually quite easily add elements dynamically in the ViewController class after you have loaded the nib. I can add something else giving an example.

Comment: If it were my choice I would have avoided this entirely by just using a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/) @Rhenz ... to be honest, I think that is really what you should be doing.

Comment: That what I thought of at first but we can't change the dots of the pagecontrol into page numbers like that. If you were to do this, how would you do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120925/discussion-between-michael-fourre-and-rhenz).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have a UICollectionView with a cell for each of these buttons. That's a better way of doing this, and you can lay it out again when the screen rotates and it changes width.

Those cells will layout offset to the left. You can solve that this way:

```
let pageNumberViewTotalWidth = 30 * count + (pageNumberViewDistance * count - 1)

self.collectionView.contentInset.left = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - pageNumberViewTotalWidth) / 2
```

The labels aren't showing up because you're setting their frame's x to be the same as the page number view's x. It's frame should be relative to it's superview, in this case `pageNumberView`.

Comment: Would UICollectionView can handle to view/display the page number if the page number is not visible to the screen already?

Comment: You'll adding the label to each cell in a delegate function, so you'll be avoiding the problem you're into right now.

Answer (score 1):

**First Question of yours  "how can I center the subviews of scrollview?"**

Solution: lets suppose you have in total 50 pages and you want to show 5 pages at a time in the scrollview.

Then make 10 subviews of equal widths where each subview width will be equal to visible portion of the collection view that is

```
   self.view.size.width - 2*(width of toggle button)
```

Then in each container view add 5 of your pageNumberView placed at equal distance

```
   lets pageNumberViewWidth = container.width/5 - 2*margin

   now pageNumberView frame will be (margin,0,pageNumberViewWidth,height)
```

In this way in each container view your pageNumberViews will be placed equally and it will look as if you have centred them.

**Second Question  "Why is that I can only see 1 label inside the view?"**

Answer : Its because you are setting label frame incorrectly

```
  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(pageNumberViewX, 0, 30, 30))
```

Here label is the subview of pageNumberView So you have to set its frame according to its parent's view which is pageNumberView, so change it to

```
  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
```

First time it was right because pageNumberViewX is 0 for first iteration after that it become some positive value which makes its frame shifted to right but its parent's width is small so its not visible to you.

**Third Question : "How can I scroll to the selected page if the page number is not visible already in the scrollview?"**

For this you need to find the frame of your selected page:

you can do that by using the offset that you used to create pageNumberView.

(width of each pageNumberView)*pageNumber = starting point of the required pageNumberView.

```
  let frame : CGRect = CGRectMake(calculated offset above, 0,30, 30)
 //where you want to scroll 

  self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated:true)
```

I hope this will help you in solving your problem

**Edit for first problem**

```
func addPageNumberViewWithCount(count: Int) {

            var containerViewX: CGFloat! = 0
            let pageNumberViewDistance: CGFloat! = 10


            let pageNumberViewPerSubview = 5
            var numberOfSubview = count/pageNumberViewPerSubview

            if(count % pageNumberViewPerSubview > 0){
                numberOfSubview = numberOfSubview + 1
            }

            var pagesLeft = count

            for i in 1...numberOfSubview {

                var pageNumberViewX: CGFloat! = 0

                let containerView : UIView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(containerViewX,0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height))

                if(pagesLeft < pageNumberViewPerSubview){
                    for k in 1...pagesLeft{

                    }
                }
                else{
                    for j in 1...pageNumberViewPerSubview{
                        let pageNumberView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(pageNumberViewX, 0, 30, 30))
                        pageNumberView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                        pageNumberView.layer.cornerRadius = pageNumberView.frame.height / 2
                        pageNumberView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                        pageNumberView.clipsToBounds = true

                        // add number label
                        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
                        label.text = "\(i)"
                        label.textAlignment = .Center
                        pageNumberView.addSubview(label)

                        // update x for next view
                        pageNumberViewX = pageNumberView.frame.origin.x + pageNumberView.frame.width + pageNumberViewDistance

                        containerView.addSubview(pageNumberView)
                    }

                    containerViewX = containerViewX + scrollView.frame.size.width
                    // add view inside scrollview
                    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

                    pagesLeft = pagesLeft - pageNumberViewPerSubview
                }






                if i == count {
                    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfSubview*scrollView.frame.size.width, 30)
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi @Vivek, thank you for your very descriptive solution but can I ask for your help on the first question? I don't quite get it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sure. tell me how can i help you with that.

Comment: I don't quite get it. How can I do that programmatically? So first is i have to divide number of pages to numberOfMaxPagePerSubview? Then add each pageLabelView to containerViews? What if I have fixed width and height of pageLabelViews. And how do I get the margin? Thank you! Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: i have just edited my answer and its hectic, If you know auto layout then problem is very easy in that case.

Comment: What do you mean? How easy it is by using autolayout. I know autolayout but i dont know how to do autolayout programmatically. Thanks man!

Comment: you need to use the container view as i have mentioned and on every container view you can add constraints on the pageIndexview.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Comment: You can see the documentation in above link if you still didnt get it i will code it for you :)

Comment: Hi @Vivek, can't still figure it out how. I hope it wouldn't take much of your time to help me figure this out. Thank you..

Comment: Hi @Rhenz Please check the above answer if it is working for you or not, if it is working then please accept my answer, i will update you about the autolayout method soon.